# Object is not iterable, but becomes iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
>>> carls = [c.source.out_crushes.all().select_related().values_list('target') for c in similar_crushes]
>>> [carlid for carlid in c for c in carls]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Crush' object is not iterable
>>> for c in carls:
...   pass
... 
>>> [carlid for carlid in c for c in carls]
[(1,), (1,), (3,), (3,)]
```

Sorry for the terrible question title, but I don't know how to phrase it better, because I'm completely lost.

What's going on here? Why is it not iterable in the initial list comprehension, but when I iterate over part of it separately, it becomes iterable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`carls` looks like it should be a list of lists, something like `[[(1,), (2,), (3,)], [(1,), (2,)]]`

When you do  `[carlid for carlid in c for c in carls]` you are trying to iterate over the last defined value of `c` which would have been a `Crush` object from `similar_crushes`.

When you do `for c in carls:` you redefine `c` as the last element in the `carls` list, which is a list of `PK`s tuples, which is iterable.

```
for i in range(100):
   pass
print i
# out : 99
```